# Gesture to text

Tags: ios, drawing, ocr

I'm trying to develop app, where user is asked a question with possible answers (a,b,d). I want him, to draw his answer. For this, there are some tutorials, e.g.[this one](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/tutorial-drawing-to-the-screen.132024/). Next part is converting this to nsstring. One option would be to use OCR Library like [Terresact](https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios) It is however very complicated just to compile it. I'm not sure if it'll work even if I manage to compile it, as you need to configure possible fonts, and drawn letter doesn't probably match any known font. Therefore I'd like to ask, if you guys know about any other method how to achieve same result. (Drawing on a view, converting it to string and compare it with letters).

Comment: what about a custom `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more holex? I've read some tutorials on UIGestureRecognizers and now I know, that I can detect circle etc.. but I'm really confused as how to use it to recognize various numbers, letters, etc..

Comment: you have to create an inherited class of the `UIGestureRecognizer` and  have to override the `–touches...` methods to detect the fingers movement on the screen, and when the movement shaped a desired curve (letters, circle, checkmarks, etc..) you have to set the `state` to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` and you will get a feedback from your custom `UIGestureRecognizer` class about the custom gesture is recognised. you have to define each gesture programmatically for each letter.

Comment: But that means, that when user "draws" shape differently than me, it won't get recognized, right?

Comment: the custom `UIGestureRecognizer` should recognise the sequence and curve only. for instance, if you create a recogniser for the checkmarks, you should check the angle between the two lines and it would be great if the second line of the checkmark should be longer than the first one. it looks easy but the letters are more difficult, because you write the same letter different from I would, e.g. the small letter `f`, maybe you don't write any curve for the letter, but I do two loops, and for these you would need different gesture recognisers. so, it could be a bit complicated, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be very interesting topic.. I'm currently interested only in recognizing numbers.. This can be tough as well (e.g number 2 with bottom loop, without loop) as you said. That's why I thought about using some 3rd party library, like Terresact.. So you recommend using gestureRecognizer over those libraries? Btw, you should make an answer, so I can upvote/accept it.. You are really nice for taking time with me :)

Comment: you can use 3rd time library, because it could work, and probably it is easier to implement them than creating gesture recognisers for each letter or symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create an inherited class of the `UIGestureRecognizer` and have to override the

```
–touches...:withEvent:
```

methods to detect the proper fingers movement for recognising the curve you'd like. it could be a letter, or an abstract shape as well, or anything else.

when the fingers' movement shaped a desired curve (letters, circle, checkmarks, etc..) you need to set the `state` to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` and you will get a feedback from your custom `UIGestureRecognizer` class about the custom gesture is recognised.

you have to define each gesture programmatically for each letter or shape.

the custom `UIGestureRecognizer` should recognise the sequence and curve only to be much more generic, because no one writes the lines or curves the exact same size.

for instance, if you create a recogniser for the checkmarks, you should check the angle between the two lines on the fly and it would be great if the second line of the checkmark should be longer than the first one. it looks easy but the letters are more difficult, because you write the same letter different from I would, e.g. the small letter `f`, maybe you don't write any curve for the letter, but I do two loops, and I won't mention the lowercase or uppercase versions of the letters.

therefore, for these you would need different gesture recognisers.

so, it could be a bit complicated, unfortunately.

however, you can use 3rd part ORC libraries (as you wanted originally), because it could work, and probably it is easier to implement a ready-to-use library than creating gesture recognisers for each letter or symbol.

Comment: Thanks for your advices holex. I'll try to work with custom gesture recognizer and if I give up, I'll try to work with teresact.